# Use DBIx::Class with a single result class definition to handle several tables with the same structure

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have several (~100 and counting) MySQL tables with more than 50M entries each. The thing is that all this tables have **exactly the same structure** and I would like to create a single result class for them in DBIx::class. 
For example consider a bunch of tables of the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users_table_1 (
  name TINYTEXT,
  username TINYTEXT
);
CREATE TABLE users_table_2 (
  name TINYTEXT,
  username TINYTEXT
);
...
```

I would like to be able to do the following without having to create a result class for each one of the tables.

```
my $users_1_rs = $schema->resultset('User_table_1');
my $users_2_rs = $schema->resultset('User_table_2');
...
```

I am new to DBIx::Class and the only two possible solutions that I could come up with are:

1. For each of the tables use something like [DBIx::Class::DynamicSubclass](http://search.cpan.org/~syber/DBIx-Class-DynamicSubclass-0.03/lib/DBIx/Class/DynamicSubclass.pm) to subclass from a base result class with all common functionality. The disadvantage is that this way I still need to write a class (although a small one) for every single one of my tables.
2. Use [DBIx::Class::Loader](http://search.cpan.org/~blblack/DBIx-Class-Loader-0.21/lib/DBIx/Class/Loader.pm) and create the classes automatically from the database itself. However, I don't find this solution very elegant and robust for my needs.

Could someone point me to a more elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: You should probably be rethinking your schema design. Bad data structure leads to bad code and bad applications. If you are storing the same type of data in 100 different tables, there is a good chance you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I'd also use DBIx::Class::DynamicSubclass for common columns but if the whole table is exactly the same I'm with jondanm that you should rethink your database design. Maybe you're better of with a single table that has an additional type column?

Comment: @jordanm and abraxxa thank you for your comments. I agree with you regarding the schema design but this is something that has been done for optimization reasons. Note that each of the tables is properly indexed, partitioned and sub-partitioned so that the individual indexes (MyISAM) remain small enough to fit in memory and take full advantage of partition pruning. If I would put all these tables into one, I would very soon end up with a solution whose performance does not scale well for my needs.

Comment: @mns So if you need to find a specific user, you need to query up to 100 tables? Relationships to other tables? I guess you don't have foreign key constraints since it's MyISAM.

Comment: @jordanm the table names I used here are an abstraction of my actual real problem. In my real world problem there is absolutely no connection among the tables and I always know _in advance_ which table I need to use for my queries. No interest in the query "Find user in any of the tables" it's always the query "Find user in table X"

Comment: @mns I am facing same problem as yours. What solution did you find to your problem?

Comment: @bvnbhati I used the approach described in the accepted answer. You can find my code [here](https://github.com/mnsmar/GenOO/tree/master/lib/GenOO/Data/DB/DBIC/Species)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a *metaprogramming* API within `DBIx::Class` for dynamically creating table classes.

In lieu of delving into the (rather large `DBIx::Class`) docs here is an alternative example creating the classes in plain Perl *metaprogramming*:

```
package MySchema;
use strict;
use warnings;
use parent 'DBIx::Class::Schema';

our @tables = map { 'users_table_' . $_ } 1..2;

require DBIx::Class::Core;

# build table classes for users_tables_*
for my $table (@MySchema::tables) {
    my $t = "MySchema::$table";
    {
        no strict 'refs';
        @{$t . '::ISA'} = qw/DBIx::Class::Core/;
    }
    $t->table($table);
    $t->add_columns(qw/name username/);
}

__PACKAGE__->load_classes(@MySchema::tables);

1;
```

In my simple tests the above worked for me :)

Comment: Thanks. I like the "dirty and elegant" _metaprogramming_ solutions ;) This would certainly do the trick however it would make it hard to add extra functionality in the future. Sure one could add extra functionality through the `add_columns` method but what about adding extra methods not coupled to a table column - that would be impossible right?

Comment: I don't think there should be any problem adding methods.  For eg. to add method to this *Result* class just requires:  `*{$t . '::some_method'} = sub { ... };`

Comment: and/or just make all the `MySchema::users_table_*` a subclass of a new `MySchema::UsersTableBase` and then make this the subclass of `DBIx::Class::Core`

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest using "from" parameter in search function:

```
...resultset('TableA')->search({}, { from=>'TableB'});
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting idea, I haven't thought of actually changing the result set with a "from". Is this a search attribute cause I could not find it in the documentation? Still though, I would prefer staying closer to a subclassing type of solution.